# difflib.get_close_matches() - Help getting desired result

Tags: python, list, sorting, difflib

The basic gist of the program is to start with a list of employee names, then sort it. Wait for user to input "end" to stop populating the list of names (I have 100 names, I cut it short for the example). Afterwards, the user can enter an employee name and the program will run difflib.get_close_matches().

Here's the question; I'm getting a syntax error for get_close_matches. How should I be entering the difflib differently? Also; if you have any tips for making the code more efficient, please also state how and why it's more efficient. I'm fairly inexperienced with Python, so be gentle, eh?

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
import difflib
employeeNames = ['Colton','Jayne','Barb','Carlene','Dick','Despina']
employeeNames.sort()
endInput = input('Type "end" to view list of names.\n\n')
if endInput == "end":
    userEmpName = input("Please enter the employee name you're searching for. We'll return the best match on record."
get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)
```

Comment: also adding full traceback would be much better.

Comment: @Lafexlos : I'm willing to do that, if you give me the information on how to do so. >.>'

Comment: add the full error you get. which line, which function etc..

Comment: That is the full error; invalid syntax error won't run the code to give more information. I need to fix the way it's worded in the code in order to get it to a point where it has problems in run-time. ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors:
Match this code with yours:

```
import difflib
employeeNames = ['Colton','Jayne','Barb','Carlene','Dick','Despina']
employeeNames.sort()
endInput = raw_input('Type "end" to view list of names.\n\n')
if endInput == "end":
    userEmpName = raw_input("Please enter the employee name you're searching for. We'll return the best match on record.")
    print difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)
```

1. you didn't  close the open brace in `input()` method.
2. I suggest using `raw_input()` instead of using `input()` while dealing with strings.
3. you should use the `classname.method()` if you have imported only the class (in your case `import difflib`) so use `difflib.get_close_matches(string,list,n)` instead.
4. You need to use `print` statement before the returned value.

Also `get_close_matches()` should be called inside of `if` because if `endInput!='end'` then `NameError` will occur for `userEmpName`.

**EDIT:**

I should have asked you about your python interpreter version.
The print line should use braces like this.

`print(difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1))`

The reason is in `python 2.x` print is a `statement`(as I mentioned in 4rth point) but in `python 3.x` its a `function`.

Comment: I tried to run your code, I get the same error message as I did in mine; invalid syntax. It's highlighting "difflib" after print.

Also; thanks for the advice. I'll try to incorporate that as I can. :)

Comment: I'm away from my computer until I get back from work, but I'll run it again when I come home and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I don't seem to have the same IDLE editor as you; `print` doesn't turn orange, and `raw_input` doesn't turn purple.

Here's what I get when I run it: [link](http://i162.photobucket.com/albums/t280/gorak_01/difflibError_zps233fec06.png)

Comment: And don't worry about the differences of `print` its only because I am using python 2.7 and you are using python 3.3

Comment: Hey hey! It's workin' like a charm now. Thanks for the help with the code, and the explanation as to why the syntax error kept popping up. I'll make sure to remember this for later.

Comment: I'm adding a bit to the code where if the GCM name isn't the name of the person they wanted, then discard the closest match and re-run the function and call the second-closest match (now first, since the function would throw out the first match).

Comment: Do you have any comments on if this can be written better?

Here's what I have so far: 


`def throwout(pickedName):`
    `employeeNames.remove(pickedName)`
    `pickedName = difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)`
   ` print(pickedName)`
   ` userFirstInput = input("Is this the first name of the person you're looking for? Type 'Yes' or 'No'.")`

Comment: you can ask a separate question...and link me there...this looks messy to read

Comment: Good point, here it is: [new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517842/difflib-get-close-matches-throw-out-names-in-a-list-if-first-answer-isnt-correc)