# difflib.get_close_matches throw out names in a list if first answer isn't correct

Tags: python, list, sorting, difflib

Here's an updated version from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494177/difflib-get-close-matches-help-getting-desired-result). I'm adding to the code where if the get_close_matches name isn't the name of the person they wanted, then discard the closest match and re-run the function and grab the second-closest match (now first, since the function would throw out the first match).

Do you have any comments on how this can be written better? And work. >.>

Here's what I have so far:

```
def throwout(pickedName):
    employeeNames.remove(pickedName)
    pickedName = difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)
    print(pickedName)
    userNameOK = input("Is this the name of the person you're looking for?\n\n Type 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n")



employeeNames = ['Colton','Jayne','Barb','Carlene','Dick','Despina']


employeeNames.sort()


userEmpName = input("Please enter the employee name you're searching for. We'll return the best match on record.")


pickedName = difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)
print(pickedName)


userNameOK = input("Is this the name of the person you're looking for?\n\n Type 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n")


if userNameOK == "N" or "n":
    if pickedName in employeeNames:
        throwout(pickedName)
    else:
        break
else:
    break
```

Error for running out of names in the list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/employee1.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(userAnswer + " is the right choice.\n")
NameError: global name 'userAnswer' is not defined
```

I understand that to mean that since the list of names has no more names from removing them all, the global variable "userAnswer" is then undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of creating a function to throw out the names from list as `list.remove(name)` does the same thing in a single line.

```
import difflib

employeeNames = ['Colton','Coltron','Colty','Jayne','Barb','Carlene','Dick','Despina']
employeeNames.sort()
userEmpName = raw_input("Please enter the employee name you're searching for. We'll return the best match on record.")

while True:
    global Answer
    pickedName = difflib.get_close_matches(userEmpName, employeeNames, 1)

    print(pickedName)
    print employeeNames

    if len(pickedName)==0:
        break

    userNameOK = raw_input("Is this the name of the person you're looking for?\n\n Type 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n")

    if (userNameOK=='n' or userNameOK=='N'):
        employeeNames.remove(pickedName[0])

    else:
        Answer=pickedName[0]
        break

print Answer+" is the right choice"
```

However using a global variable is generally bad practice so you can make a function to do all this thing and return the correct `Answer`

Also as `employeeNames` is modified every time a Name is removed from it should be better to create a copy of the list and work on that particular list

Comment: With a bit of jerry-rigging for my IDLE editor I got it to run quite well.

How would the function look (differently than the one I put up)?

Lastly; how would you go about maintaining a removal list? It doesn't seem like it'll do much good for this particular program, since it isn't meant to be re-run unless the picked name isn't the name the user wanted.

Thanks for the help, too. It's much appreciated.

Comment: You can create a function lets say `nameLookUp(employeeNames)` and add the whole code after the line `employeeNames.sort()` to it.....

the argument to the function is `employeeNames` list

Comment: Yes you are right for this program it is not useful but I was just thinking that if it is just a part of a bigger project where the list could be needed again.
For that you create a copy and pass that to the function `nameLookUp()`.......
`newList=oldList[:]` this is how you copy a list.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. I ran into another problem, there's an error when all the names get removed (none were the correct name for the user). I tried an if statement to check when the list was at it's last name and choose it, but that didn't work out. Thoughts?

Comment: add the `test case` at which you are getting error and also add the `traceback` of the error to the edits.

Comment: I don't understand where to put 'test case' at. Tried looking it up [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), but to no avail. :/

Comment: I also added the traceback to the main question, and my interpretation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't initialised `Answer` variable.
Before the `while` loop just put this `Answer='No One'`